# Reading attribute of a property using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, c#-4.0

I need to read the attribute of a property using reflection

For example I get the following :

```
    [XmlElement("Id")]
    [CategoryAttribute("Main"), ReadOnly(true),
    Description("This property is auto-generated")]
    [RulesCriteria("ID")]
    public override string Id
    {
        get { return _ID; }
        set
        {
            _ID = value;
        }
    }
```

i want to get the " read only "value of this property using reflection
can anybody help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to write the code for your case without knowing the Type name. Hope below example helps.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

public class Myproperty
{
    private string caption = "Default caption";
    public string Caption
    {
        get{return caption;}
        set {if(caption!=value) {caption = value;}
        }
    }
}

class Mypropertyinfo
{
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nReflection.PropertyInfo");

        // Define a property.
        Myproperty Myproperty = new Myproperty();
        Console.Write("\nMyproperty.Caption = " + Myproperty.Caption);

        // Get the type and PropertyInfo.
        Type MyType = Type.GetType("Myproperty");
        PropertyInfo Mypropertyinfo = MyType.GetProperty("Caption");

        // Get and display the attributes property.
        PropertyAttributes Myattributes = Mypropertyinfo.Attributes;

        Console.Write("\nPropertyAttributes - " + Myattributes.ToString());

        return 0;
    }
}
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.attributes.aspx)

Comment: Look at here Example 18-2 http://oreilly.com/catalog/progcsharp/chapter/ch18.html

Comment: it is very helpful but in:                               foreach(Object attribute in attributes)
    {
        BugFixAttribute bfa = (BugFixAttribute) attribute;
        Console.WriteLine("\nBugID: {0}", bfa.BugID);
        Console.WriteLine("Programmer: {0}", bfa.Programmer);
        Console.WriteLine("Date: {0}", bfa.Date);
        Console.WriteLine("Comment: {0}", bfa.Comment);
    }
i want to make a condition in this loop to catch the attibute read only and know its value , you get me?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static bool PropertyReadOnlyAttributeValue(PropertyInfo property)
{
    ReadonlyAttribute attrib = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(property, typeof(ReadOnlyAttribute));
    return attrib != null && attrib.IsReadOnly;
}

public static bool PropertyReadOnlyAttributeValue(Type type, string propertyName)
{
    return PropertyReadOnlyAttributeValue(type.GetProperty(propertyName));
}

public static bool PropertyReadOnlyAttributeValue(object instance, string propertyName)
{
    if (instance != null)
    {
        Type type = instance.GetType();
        return PropertyReadOnlyAttributeValue(type, propertyName);
    }
    return false;
}
```